# ASP.Net webform reminder popup at every five minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to show reminder popup with details of meetings at every five minutes before 30 minutes of meeting start. I have tried to use `window.setInterval` in my application master page in `$(document).ready`. The problem is if user stays on same page for 4 minutes and then when he navigate to another page, interval reset and popup is show at 9 minutes (4 on previous page + 5 on new page). How can i implement reminder popup with accurate timing in asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by making the popups appear on a specific time, instead of using a countdown relative to the point of the page being loaded. You'll have to write a bit of Javascript to run on loading  the page (an interval that checks every few seconds or so) and it needs to know the time when to stop showing stuff. You could consider using MOD or a list of times to figure out if it's time to show a popup.

Comment: Much better approach than time countdown. Now i have timer with interval of 1 minute and  i am comparing current minute to decide whether to show popup or not and gives more accuracy than countdown